# Is there a limit for TextureAtlas size?

Tags: android, libgdx

I am new in game development and want to develop a phone game. I am trying to make a complex animation in libgdx, which consists of nearly 300 images (655 × 1160 each, together in size of 42MB). Is there a limit in how big textureAtlas image can be or how many pictures it takes? Will there be a problem if I render 7 animations at once, while 2 of them are as complex as this one (activated skill), but others are just simple character movements?

Answer (score 4):

The atlas can be as big as you have RAM for. The more RAM you have, the bigger atlases you can load.

On Android, you may have problems loading 42 MB big images as it's a lot of allocation at once. There have been multiple posts on Stack Overflow about just that problem. You just have to try loading it and see what happens. If the game crashes with an OutOfMemoryException, you have to make it smaller.

Because Android is a platform with a lot of variation in hardware (some devices have 512 MB total ram while others have 6 GB) there's no "hard limit" to what you can load in on a platform basis. It depends on what device and how much RAM is available (free RAM)<sub>Disclaimer: this answer is old and doesn't represent a realistic RAM distribution anymore. With certain phones having as much as 16 gigs of RAM and most flagships boasting at least 4 GB, 42 MB shouldn't (realistically) be a problem anymore. Android RAM allocation is still one of the weirdest systems in existence, and sufficiently large bitmaps may throw an exception separately. Bitmaps in this case do mean through the Bitmap class in "regular" android, and not directly OpenGL and/or LibGDX.</sub>

What the TextureAtlas actually contains (complex animations of 30 images vs 2 massive images) doesn't matter. As long as you load it (and manage to get it into memory without the game crashing) there's not going to be a problem rendering it. The framerate may drop though (depending on hardware and how much you actually render) but unless you render thousands of images at once it shouldn't be a problem

Adding `android:largeHeap="true"` in the manifest is also helpful.